# rigid black 4" pipe underground about 15" impact resistant?

Tags: pvc

I have a rigid underground drain pipe buried about 18" .  Top of pipe may be only 14" under the dirt.  A heavy bucket truck drove over it in winter (Wisconsin weather for January) to trim trees.  Truck has 4 rear wheels and two front.  If one side of the double rear wheel show signs of 2.5" dip in the lawn after the thaw is it likely the pipe cracked?

Comment: Just dig down and have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Minnesota (similar climate). It's been a fairly mild winter so far, but we did have one deep cold spell. All told, It was probably enough to freeze your soil sufficiently to bear that weight. The groove in your lawn is partly due to the low-density grass and topsoil, but it's hard to say without photos.

That said, if your soil is very dry or sandy, it may have shifted enough to crack the pipe. At a temperature of 10 or 20 degrees F it won't be very flexible.

One way to find out....

Comment: Isherwood, Thanks for response.  I did dig down only 12" and didn't find the top of the pipe so My guess it may be deeper or I missed it.  I did dig over the rut line.   Top 9" of dirt was moist then I hit sand mix which appeared dry.  Since the artisian well runs constantly and the deeper dirt was dry I am assuming there is not a crack.  You have any idea how much a cherry picker with 6 wheels and with a utility cab weights?  If The rut isn't  exactly OVER the pipe would that be better?.

Comment: It's all speculation at this point. I'm afraid I don't have much to add.